# Extension of a linear map with condition on eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a vector subspace of the Euclidean space and let $L\colon S\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a linear map such that $L$ is an isometry between $S$ and $L(S)$. Assume also that there is no $v\in S$ such that $Lv=-v$, $v\neq 0$.

Can I always extend $L$ to an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, say $\tilde{L}\in O(m)$, such that $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $\tilde{L}$?

I tried the following:
Extend $L$ to an isometry $L_1$ of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, if $L_1$ has eigenvalue $-1$, compose $L_1$ with reflections that fix $L(S)$ and modify the eigenspace associated to $-1$. However I couldn't conclude that the resulting isometry does not have (new) eigenvectors with eigenvalue $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote $I_{k,m} = (\delta_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{m,k}$. Then your problem is equivalent to the following:

> Let $X\in\mathbb R^{m\times k}$, $m>k$, be isometric (i.e., $X^TX = I_k$) such
>   that $X+I_{k,m}$ has full rank. Then there is $Y\in\mathbb R^{m\times(m-k)}$ such that $U = [X|Y]$ is orthogonal and $U+I_m$ is regular.

To see this, let us show that we find a unit vector $v\in\ker X^T$ such that $[X\,|\,v]+I_{k+1,m}$ has full rank. Then the claim follows by induction.

Note that $\ker X^T$ is $(m-k)$-dimensional, so we always find a unit vector $v$ in there. Assume that for one such vector the matrix $A=[X\,|\,v]+I_{k+1,m}$ does not have full rank. Choose $k$ rows with indices $n_1,\ldots,n_k$ in $X+I_{k,m}$ (except the $(k+1)$-th!) and let $Y\in\mathbb R^{(k+1)\times k}$ be the matrix with these rows and the $(k+1)$-th row at the bottom. Now, set $w = (v_{n_1},\ldots,v_{n_k},v_{k+1}+1)^T$ and consider $B := [Y\,|\,w]\in\mathbb R^{(k+1)\times(k+1)}$. As $B$ is a submatrix of $A$, it is singular. Using the Laplace expansion for the determinant with respect to the last column and denoting by $a_j$ the determinant of $Y$ with the $j$-th row deleted ($j=1,\ldots,k+1$), we get
$$
-a_1w_1 + (-1)^2 a_2w_2 + \ldots + (-1)^{k}a_{k}w_{k} + (-1)^{k+1}a_{k+1}(v_{k+1}+1) = 0.
$$
Assuming that also $[X\,|-v]+I_{k+1,m}$ does not have full rank, we similarly get
$$
a_1w_1 + (-1)^3 a_2w_2 + \ldots + (-1)^{k+1}a_{k}w_{k} + (-1)^{k+2}a_{k+1}(v_{k+1}-1) = 0.
$$
Adding these two equations, we obtain $a_{k+1}=0$. The vector ${\bf a} = (-a_1,a_2,\ldots,(-1)^{k+1}a_{k+1})^T$ is the $(k+1)$-column of the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) $\operatorname{adj}(B)$ of $B$. Since $B\operatorname{adj}(B) = \det(B)I_{k+1} = 0$, it follows that $B{\bf a} = 0$. But the last entry of ${\bf a}$ is zero and so $Y{\bf b}=0$, where ${\bf b} = (-a_1,a_2,\ldots,(-1)^ka_k)^T$. If $Y$ had full rank, then ${\bf b}=0$ and hence $a_j=0$ for $j=1,\ldots,k+1$. But this means that all $k\times k$-submatrices of $Y$ are singular and so $Y$ cannot have full rank.

This shows that all $k\times k$-submatrices of $X+I_{k,m}$ are singular and so $X+I_{k,m}$ cannot have full rank, contrary to the assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Extend $L$ to an isometry $\tilde{L}$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$. Suppose 
that $\tilde{L}$ has eigenvalue $-1$ with eigenspace $E_{-1}$ of dimension $\dim E_{-1}=k>0$. We have by assumption that 
$E_{-1}\cap S=E_{-1}\cap L(S)=\{0\}$. Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$ 
be an orthonormal basis of $E_{-1}$ and set
$$
P=L(S)\oplus \mbox{span}\{e_2,\ldots,e_k\}.
$$
Let $\xi\in P^\perp$ be a unit vector colinear with the
orthogonal projection of $e_1$ in $P^\perp$. Let $\eta\in\mathbb{R}^m$ be such
that $\tilde{L}\eta=\xi$ and let $H$ be the hyperplane $\{\eta\}^\perp$.
If $R$ is the reflection with respect to the hyperplane 
$\{\xi\}^\perp$, then the isometry $L_1=R\tilde{L}$ satisfies
$L_1v=\tilde{L}v$ for any $v\in H$ since $\tilde{L}v\in\{\xi\}^\perp$.

Given that $\langle\eta,e_1\rangle=-\langle\xi,e_1\rangle\neq 0$, there is 
$v\in H$ such that $\eta_1+v$ is colinear with $e_1$.
Hence
$$
\tilde{L}(\eta+v)=\xi+\tilde{L}v=-\eta-v.
$$
We claim that no vector of the form $\eta+u$, $u\in H$, is 
an eigenvector associated to $-1$ of $L_1$. If otherwise, then
$$
L_1(\eta+u)=-\xi+\tilde{L}u=-\eta-u.
$$
for some $u\in H$. From the last two equations we obtain
$$
\tilde{L}(u+v)=-2\eta-(u+v).
$$
Then
$$
\|\tilde{L}(u+v)\|^2=4+\|u+v\|^2
$$
which contradicts that $\tilde{L}$ is an isometry and proves the claim.

We have proved that the eigenspace of $L_1$ associated 
to $-1$ is contained in $H$, in fact, it is 
$\mbox{span}\{e_2\dots...,e_k\}$. Therefore, by composing $\tilde{L}$ with 
$k$ appropriate reflections we obtain an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^m$ that extends $L$ and does not have $-1$ as an eigenvalue.